# Does rsync change file content (dealing with hardlinks)?

Tags: rsync, synchronization, hardlink

Imagine I have a file `remote/A` which syncs to `local/A` and `local/B` is a hardlink of `local/A`. Is there a threat that on a next `remote/A` change and synchronization `rsync` will not delete `local/A` but only replace/add some part to it, thus changing `local/B` (because of hardlinking)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With standard options, `rsync` will copy the new file assigning it a semi-random name, then it will rename the new file with the original name. In this process, no writes are directed at the original file, preserving its hadlinks.

On the other side, using the non-default`--inplace` option **will** overwrite the original file and its hardlinks.

Anyway, I strongly suggest to give a look at `--link-dest` option, which is extremely useful for deduplicated backups.